# How to set Page title for page with content type "image/jpeg"

Tags: vb.net, content-type, system.drawing, page-title

I created a page `GetImage.aspx` of `ContentType="image/jpeg"` that displays an image.

```
Page.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
Page.Response.Flush()
```

However, when I download the image, the image is saved as `"GetImage.jpg"`. Is there a way where I can change the title of the saved image without having to create another page with a different name?

In other words, how to set page titles for pages of `ContentType="image/jpeg"`?

Comment: You're looking for `Content-Disposition`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with content disposition.

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=somefile.name")
```